# Getting git log to show merge committer for a given commit

Tags: git

I am trying to get "git log" to show a list of commits for a given branch in a single line format.

At the moment I have:

```
git log --no-merges --pretty='format:%cN, %s'
```

Which produces:

```
Sarah Developer, Updated the flange pipe
Fred Tester, Implemented new testing methodology
```

But what I'd like to add is the name of the committer of the *merge* commit that got the commit into this branch (if there is one) to the end, such that I get something like...

```
Sarah Developer, Updated the flange pipe, Pauline Techarchitect
Fred Tester, Implemented new testing methodology, Hannah Senior
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean append the person who merged the original pull request?

Comment: `--no-merges` directs `git log` not to print anything about the merge commits. The merge commits are the ones that carry the names of the committer. To get those names, *don't* use `--no-merges`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that such functionality exists in git out of the box.

The idea that something like that might be possible seems to be based on a slightly inaccurate understanding of the git branch concept.

Technically, in git (contrary to some other VCS) a branch is just a pointer to a commit.
The branch concept does not include a history of which commits the branch pointer previously pointed to.

*(Maybe not completely true... There is the branch reflog, but that only includes branch events which occurred locally, so not feasible to use for something like this)*

If I have a commit history like this:

```
*   59817c7 - (HEAD -> master) merge commit
|\  
| * 4e5cf26 - commit b
* | dd09b38 - commit a
|/  
* e27e6cc - base commit
```

You could not tell if `commit a` or `commit b` was made on master branch, and the other one on a side branch. (Unless you read information from default merge commit messages).
Both commits are equal. Both are a part of the history of the master branch, because the history of the master branch includes all commits reachable from the commit which the master branch points to.

The branch concept as we like to think of it colloquially (ie. one of the parents of a merge commit "is" the master branch and the other "is" the feature branch) is defined by your workflow, but it is not technically built into the git information model.